# Understanding recursive

Tags: c++

I've been trying to get a better understanding of recursive functions, and I was working on a problem trying to figure out why it wasn't working properly.

I want it to go through the array, and when it finds a 0, to return true.

But the function stills return true when there's no zero.

Here is my code:

```
bool containZero(int randomArray[], int length)
{
    if(randomArray[length] == 0)
        return true;
    else
    {
        return containZero(randomArray, length - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Think of when there is no 0 in the array. Add a base case for it

Comment: Also bear in mind that in C++ indices start at `0`, and most likely `length` is out of range.

Comment: "*it wasn't working properly*" - what exactly is not working? You need to be more specific. What does the input array actually look like? What is the outcome you are expecting, and what is the actual outcome?

Comment: The function would always return true even when there wasn't a 0 in the array.

Comment: @scarydog1 How would it return `false` if there is no branch that **could** return `false`?

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is not handling the possibility that the array may not actually contain a zero. You need to stop iterating when the end of the array is reached.

You are also accessing the array out of bounds from the very 1st iteration, and also if no zero is found.

Not only that, but there is no branch of your recursion logic that *ever* returns `false`. Your `return` statements are always returning `true`.

Try this instead:

```cpp
// this searches backwards...
bool containZero(int randomArray[], int length)
{
    if (length <= 0)
        return false;
    --length;
    if (randomArray[length] == 0)
        return true;
    return containZero(randomArray, length);
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/Um83v8)

Alternatively:

```cpp
// this searches forwards...
bool containZero(int randomArray[], int length)
{
    if (length <= 0)
        return false;
    if (randomArray[0] == 0)
        return true;
    return containZero(randomArray+1, length-1);
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/gC79G2)

Comment: `if (length <= 0)`, I think that `length[0]` is still a valid index?

Comment: @justANewbie the input to `length` is expected to be the size of the array, not an index. It is internally converted into an index while looping. See the demo I posted. Index 0 does get accessed.

Comment: Yup, I understand it now, thanks very much!

Comment: One more question (not related to the question): I remember that the question is closed before you post the answer, so how can you still post it? Maybe because you have a C++ gold badge?

Comment: @justANewbie I posted my initial answer before the question was closed. I can freely edit my answer regardless of the question being closed. However, in any case, there is also a very small window of opportunity where answers can still be posted within a few seconds after a question is closed. I've done that a few times before.

Comment: Huh, it's weird. I checked the timeline, and it says that the question was closed before you post the answer.

Comment: See [This answer was posted *after* the question was closed, how is that possible?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252711/)